# Catch empty String. Which exception to use?

Tags: java, swing, exception

As the title suggests I am trying to catch an empty String. I have a class (the class of the object I am trying to create) that throws an Exception when the String is null or empty (check with str.isEmpty).
When I try to create the object with an empty String in another class it works as intended and throws an Exception. However, I want this class to Catch that Exception and notify the user. But it never seems to Catch the Exception, even if I try to write Catch(Exception exc). 
Now I know a null or empty String is not illegal. But my intention was that the object class was supposed to make it so. Instead it seems as if the catch block doesn't care at all. I am starting to think that I would have to create my own exception class of some sort... or is there something I am missing? Here are the relevant parts of the code:

The object class constructor:

```
    public Valueables(String name){
    //name.trim().length() == 0
    if(name == null || name.isEmpty()){
        try {
            throw new Exception("Subclasses of Valueables cannot take in an empty String or null value for the \"name\" constructor");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(2);
        }
    }
    else
        this.name = name;
}
```

The other class (the new Trinket object is a subclass of Valueables. The one with the constructor code above):

```
while(loopPassErrorControl == false){

                        //I don't think the try loop is relevant. But just to make sure...
                        //Otherwise just ignore it

                        try{
                            TrinketForm Tform = new TrinketForm();
                            answer = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(ValueablesFrame.this, Tform, "Nytt smycke", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                                    null, options , null);
                            if (answer != JOptionPane.OK_OPTION){
                            return;
                            }

                            valueablesList.add(new Trinket(Tform.getName(), Tform.getGemstones(), Tform.getMetalSelected()));
                            loopPassErrorControl = true;

                        }catch(NumberFormatException | NullPointerException exc) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(ValueablesFrame.this, "Något gick fel");
                        }
                        }
                        //Test
                        for(Valueables obj : valueablesList){
                        System.out.println(valueablesList);
                        }
```

Comment: If it's an illegal argument, why not `IllegalArgumentException`?

Comment: Do you know that you don't have to throw and catch an Exception to print its stack trace? `new Exception("message").printStackTrace();` would work too.

Comment: Where are you calling `new Valueables(name)`?

Comment: Your try catch makes no sense: you throw an exception and immediately catch it and exit the system. Also, we don't have any idea what the code of Trinket is.

Comment: Sorry Andy. Forgot to mention that Trinket is a subclass of my Valueables. And yes I have written super(name) in that subclass. Also, IllegalArgumentException didn't make any difference unfortunately.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that you are passing in a empty string then?

Comment: You should check for `name.trim().isEmpty()` (`.trim()` removes leading and trailing whitespaces) instead of `name.isEmpty()`, because `.isEmpty()` is [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty--) as _`Returns true if, and only if, length() is 0.`_. So checking the untrimmed name will probably allow it to pass if the name only consists of whitespaces.

Comment: @RegisteredUser - Ah yes. I didn't think about the whitespaces. That will be good to keep in mind. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

First throw a RuntimeException on Valuable:

```
public Valueables(String name){
    //name.trim().length() == 0
    if(name == null || name.isEmpty()){
        throw new RuntimeException("Subclasses of Valueables cannot take in an empty String or null value for the \"name\" constructor");

    }
    else
        this.name = name;
}
```

And do not catch the exception.

Second, on the other class catch a RuntimeException and show a mesage:

```
...}catch(RuntimeException exc) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(exc.getMessage());
                    }
```

Hope helped you!

Comment: Yes! I see now that I caught the exception in my object class before it got a chance to catch it in the frame class *facepalm*. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 6):

Already made a question about empty strings, an empty string is still not null so it must throw "IllegalArgumentException" if you WANT to catch it.

Answer (score -1):

try to catch it as the generic Exception, replace the NuumberFormatException and NullpointerException.

You can also do this in Java.

```
try {
    //Some Code here
} catch (NumberFormatException | NullPointerException ex) {
    //Handle NumberFormat and NullPointer exceptions here    
} catch (Exception ex) {
    //Handle generic exception here
}
```

Comment: Catching `Exception` is a bad idea unless you are unfortunate enough to have code which throws `Exception` - which you should avoid writing unless absolutely necessary, since it is the exception equivalent of returning `Object` (it provides basically no type information). Catching `Exception` is a fantastic way to hide problems later if new exceptions requiring specific handling (e.g. `InterruptedException`) are added to the method signatures.

Comment: I mentioned that I tried this. It doesn't work. Also, I imagined that catching all kinds of exceptions with Exception is ugly? Cause I imagine that Exception is a superclass of the other exceptions e.g NumberFormatException?